# Object reference exception when I try assign cell value to string

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I tried convert to string value of cell in a datagridview:

```
string t = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()== null ? String.Empty : row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(t);
```

MessageBox shows correctly value but application gives exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Value` property could be null; Try this

```
string t = row.Cells[0].Value == null ? String.Empty : row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```